# Не получается инвертировать часть строки с помощью среза

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача:

Дана строка, в которой буква h встречается как минимум два раза. Разверните последовательность символов, заключенную между первым и последним появлением буквы h, в противоположном порядке.

Мой код:

```
s = input()
one = s.find("h")
two = s.rfind("h")

answer = s[:one] + s[one:two:-1] + s[two:]

print(answer)
```

Входные данные: `In the hole in the ground there lived a hobbit`

Мой вывод:
`In thobbit`

Правильный вывод:
`In th a devil ereht dnuorg eht ni eloh ehobbit`

Знаю, что основная проблема в `s[one:two:-1]`, ибо я пытался это в отдельную переменную засунуть, выводится ничего. Объясните пожалуйста, что не так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обратном порядке же идёте от большего индекса к меньшему

```
 answer = s[:one] + s[two:one-1:-1] + s[two+1:]

 In th a devil ereht dnuorg eht ni eloh ehobbit
```

Comment: Почему s[two:one] уже не обозначает обратный порядок s[one:two]? Ведь мы начинаем с конца (two) а заканчиваем началом (one).

Comment: Если инкремент не указан - подразумевается  +1. Конец меньше начала - пустой срез, и это используется при вычисляемых границах срезов..

Comment: Кажется понял. Благодарю!